# How do I get Hibernate Filters to work in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have the following entity class:

```
@Entity
@FilterDef (name = "byLastName", parameters = @Parameter (name = "lastName", type="string"))
@Filters ({
    @Filter (name = "byLastName", condition = "lastName = :lastName")
})
public class User {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}
```

In my DAO I do this:

```
public User findById (Long id)
{
   Session s = (Session) em.getDelegate ( );
   s.enableFilter ("byLastName").setParameter ("lastName", "smith");

   User u = em.find (User.class, id);
   return (u);
}
```

Now, if I'm understanding this correctly, the filter should be applied, and any User that I try to retrieve should come back as null if the lastName does not equal "smith". The problem is that the filters don't appear to be applied. Any User that I attempt to retrieve from the database, regardless of the value of the lastName gets returned.

Am I misunderstanding how filters work? Or am I missing something in how I have this configured? Note that I'm not using hibernate.cfg.xml; everything is configured for me using JPA and annotations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters do not affect any form of look up by ids.  This is also the exact reason one-to-one and many-to-one associations cannot be filtered.

Comment: This seemed to be my problem, when I changed the code to use a query instead, it worked like a champ. I hadn't really thought about it in depth (I'm really new to the Hibernate filter thing), but I guess it makes some degree of sense to not filter when you already have the ID of a given object. Thanks for setting me straight